# What does this function definition in clojure code example do?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am following along 'Clojure in Action' and I am confused by this :

```
(defn with-log [function-to-call log-statement ]
      (fn [& args]
          (println log-statement)
          (apply  function-to-call args)))
```

This is the segment of code that has me confused. This is what I can decipher so far:

(defn with-log [function-to-call log-statement ] ..) is defining  a function with name "with-log" that takes arguments 'function-to-call' and 'log-statement' and function-to-call is a function being passed as a parameter to this function.
The next section is confusing  to me : (fn [& args] .... is an anonymous function being defined here ?  Is the 'with-log'  function returning a new function definition ?

```
(fn [& args]
          (println log-statement)
          (apply  function-to-call args))
```

So by calling (with-log somefunc "my label") -- is it just returing a new anonymous function  ? Or is it invoking  the anonymous function ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`with-log` will yield a function that, when called, will do exactly what `function-to-call` did except with the side-effect that `log-statement` will be printed to `*out*` just before `function-to-call` is evaluated using the arguments given to the anonymous function.

This is an example of the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) - extending the behaviour of an existing function by wrapping it in another function i.e. the anonymous function created by `with-log` using the `(fn ...)` form.

In order for the decorator function `with-log` to work with any conceivable `function-to-call`, the anonymous function's argument list is specified so that it can be called with number of arguments using `(fn [& args] ...)`.  When the anonymous function calls `function-to-call` it 'unwraps' the argument list with the function `apply`).

Ways to make use of `with-log` might be:

```
((with-log some-fn "Calling some-fn") arg1 arg2)
```

or

```
(defn my-fn [a b]
  (+ a b))
(def my-fn-with-logging (with-log my-fn "Calling my-fn"))

(my-fn 1 2) ; evaluates to 3
(my-fn-with-logging 1 2) ; prints "Calling my-fn" and evaluates to 3
```

Answer (score 1):

It is returning the anonymous function, and it is not being called.

For example, this would invoke the anonymous function with the given arguments:

```
((with-log some-fn "log statement") arg1 arg2)
```

This works because the function being returned is the first item in the list, which means it gets invoked just like any other function would.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. `(fn ..)` is a form which creates anonymous function. This piece of code, given a function `f` and some value `s` will return a function, which, when called, will print `s` and then invoke `f`:

```
user=> (defn with-log [function-to-call log-statement ]
      (fn [& args]
          (println log-statement)
          (apply  function-to-call args)))
#'user/with-log
user=> (with-log + "String")
#<user$with_log$fn__1 user$with_log$fn__1@147264b1>
user=> ((with-log + "String") 1 2 3)
String
6
user=>
```

Note the line starting with `#<user$...`. This is internal identifier of the anonymous function that just has been created, that is, simple call to `with-log` returns a function. And then we apply the same function (it is same in terms of its behavior; it will be different object in fact, because each call to `with-log` creates new "instance" of the same function) to a number of arguments. `"String"` string gets printed and then REPL shows us a result of `(+ 1 2 3)`.

[Here](http://clojure.org/special_forms#Special%20Forms--%28fn%20name?%20%5Bparams%2a%20%5D%20exprs%2a%29) you can learn more about it.